# How to create sliding images using simple animation Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I just started learning Objective C, I really need your help to create simple game without using Cocos2D and other difficult things.

In theory, I think it should look like this: we have an array of pictures that will by turns to slide across the screen, that is, first a picture on the screen came down on the Y axis and then its coordinates need to put on top and repeat until "Game over".
But I do not know how to do this.

Description on the picture
http://postimg.org/image/pvkwpgz4d/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a "tell me how to write my program" site. It's a site where you get help solving specific problems.

You're going to need to do your own research on how to do this. Take a stab at it, and then come back with questions about problems you're having with the approach you're using.

Comment: Okay, How animate sliding images using animateWithDuration?

Comment: You need to use one of the longer form versions that takes an options parameter, and specify linear animation. Then you need to decide if you're using auto-layout or struts-and-springs style resizing. The answer is different for each. In non auto-layout, you would just change the center property (or frame.origin, but center is better) of the view inside your animations block. The system will then animate your image view from its starting to the ending position. It's quite easy.